# I need a simile for clutching something

Tags: simile

Can someone help me? I'm writing a paper about the Grand Canyon and in it the main characters brother is is clutching the rail on the sky walk like a ____. I need a simile for this.

Comment: 'Like a limpet' is a common idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*... clutching the rail on the skywalk like a vise.*

> ### vise
>
> any of various devices, usually having two jaws that may be brought
>   together or separated by means of a screw, lever, or the like, used to
>   hold an object firmly while work is being done on it.
>
> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vise

See images here:

- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vise)
- [google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=vise&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcs8Hi4e7ZAhXpguAKHet-D5QQ_AUICygC&biw=1493&bih=827)